# 'module' object has no attribute 'X'

Tags: python, django

I have Python/Django project setup, and I have the following helper module named `adwords_utils.py` with the following structure:

```
from django.conf import settings
from googleads import adwords
import csv
import currency_helper
import logging
import sys
import StringIO

def GetDataFromCsv(path, exchangeRates, managedAccount):

def GetPerformanceReport(cid, reportType, reportFields, dateRangeType, minDate, maxDate):

def GetAmountFromMicros(micros):

def GetManagedAccounts(managerId):
```

This then utilized in my views.py in the following way:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
import adwords_utils

def account_hierarchy(request):
  manager_ids = settings.MANAGER_IDS
  managed_accounts = []
  for manager_id in manager_ids:
    managed_accounts.extend(adwords_utils.GetManagedAccounts(manager_id))
  if len(managed_accounts) > 0:
    for managed_account in managed_accounts:
      client_id = managed_account.customerId
      report_type = 'ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT'
      report_fields = ['ExternalCustomerId', 'CustomerDescriptiveName', 'Date', 'Cost']
      report_date_type = 'CUSTOM_DATE'
      report_start_date = '20141201'
      report_end_date = '20141211'
      adwords_utils.GetPerformanceReport(client_id, report_type, report_fields, report_date_type, report_start_date, report_end_date)

  return render_to_response('simple-table.html', {"managed_accounts": managed_accounts})
```

Where the problematic attributes are: `adwords_utils.GetManagedAccounts` and `adwords_utils.GetPerformanceReport`.

As you can see the helper module isn't declaring a class, because the methods aren't class-specific, and they are intended to be used as helper methods. Not sure where the problem is.

**Complete Traceback:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://104.236.122.5/account-hierarchy/

Django Version: 1.6.1
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'reporting')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/django/django_project/reporting/views.py" in account_hierarchy
  12.       managed_accounts.extend(adwords_utils.GetManagedAccounts(manager_id))

Exception Type: AttributeError at /account-hierarchy/
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'GetManagedAccounts'
```

Comment: Are you sure you're importing the module you think you're importing?

Comment: Yep, It was working when I was only using the 'GetManagedAccounts' method, but then as I started using the second one everything broke.

Comment: Please show the complete error traceback.

Comment: I have added the traceback.

Comment: Bit of a long shot: Did you spell `GetManagedAccounts` correctly in the `adwords_utils.py` file?

Comment: Have you tried to run something like this

  python -c 'import adwords_utils; print adwords_utils.GetManagedAccounts;'

Just to see if an error crops up

Comment: Yep, I am retarded. It was working at some point but only because of a remaining adwords_utils.pyc that was leftover before I moved the module inside the main project. I had to change to 'from django_project import adwords_utils'. Feel free to add as answer so I can accept.

Comment: @daniel_c05 You can add and accept your answer.